# How to populate combobox,taking values from enum

Tags: java, struts2

I have a jsp page with one combo box and I have a class which is an enum.

I want to populate my combo box in jsp and when it's populated I want to save these value in D/B how can I do it in Struts 2

```
public enum Roles {
  ONE   ("One"),
  TWO   ("Two"),
  THREE ("Three"),
  FOUR  ("Four"),
  FIVE  ("Five"),
  ALL   ("All");

  private final String displayValue;

  private Roles(String displayString){
      this.displayValue = displayString;
  }
  public String getDisplayString() {
      return displayValue;
  } 

  public static Roles getRoleOf(String displayValue){         
      if(displayValue.equals("One"))
          return ONE;
      if(displayValue.equals("Two"))
          return TWO;
      if(displayValue.equals("Three"))
          return THREE;
      if(displayValue.equals("Four"))
          return FOUR;
        if(displayValue.equals("All"))
          return ALL;
      else return ALL;
  }
}
```

Comment: Roles should be named Role. And you forgot FIVE in your getRoleOf method. You should iterate through all the values (using the static values() method) to find the one with the given name: it would make code shorter and more robust.

Comment: You may also name your roles `One` instead of `ONE`, allowing you to use `Roles.valueOf(String arg)` to get a role value (and catch an `IllegalArgumentException` if there is none).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Roles.values()` to get all the enum values and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
Roles[] allRoles = Roles.values();
for(Roles role : allRoles) {
    // add role to combo box using role.getDisplayString
}
```